# Enhydra 5 application on tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat7

I have an application using enhydra 5 framework running on a resin 2 server.
Moving this application to a tomcat 7 server is giving me issues.

I was able to get the application deployed on tomcat server, but the session data is lost between requests. I compared the values by debugging the application on tomcat and resin and found that the session values are available in resin.

Does anyone have any idea or provide me the link to get Enhydra source code.
It is a very old framework and was written in 2000.

Answer (score 1):

I did a little digging and the best I could come up with was http://www.together.at/download which appears to be where this code migrated to but there is no sign of an accessible source repository or src bundles for old versions.

It sounds like there may be a configuration problem at work here. Something as simple as looking at the HTTP headers may shed some light on what is going wrong.

Another option I sometimes use when the source code isn't immediately to hand is [JAD](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad/). The decompiled code isn't always the most readable but it is usually good enough to figure out what is going wrong.